# js ':' Expected node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, visual-studio-code

While trying to register user using nodejs and mongoose i get an error saying `[js] ':' Expected` on the `dot notation` at `User.findOne(email: res.body.email)`. 
I tried this

```
User: User.findOne(...)
```

but it raises  the following error at runtime when sending a post request from *postman*

```
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: body is not defined
    at User.User.findOne.then.user (C:\Users\Aman\Desktop\qwerty\routes\api\users.js:14:29)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)
(node:13952) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing ins
ide of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejectio
n id: 1)
```

this is my code

```
const User = require("../../Models/User");

router.post("/register", (req, res) => ({
User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
if (user) {
     show email registered before message
} else {
     do something
  });

  const newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    avatar: req.body.avatar,
    password: req.body.password
  });

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
         newUser.password = hash;
         newUser
           .save()
        });
      });
    }
  })
}));
```

Comment: I bet the error is in `else` block that is not shared...

Comment: what is the error in `else`?

Comment: and how should i fix it?

Comment: Can you please format your code better? I'm having a hard time reading where blocks begin and where they end. I was about to format it myself, but some brackets are inconsistent and I don't want to write it different than it is. Also, which line is line 14?

Comment: firstly it shouldn't be like that router.post("/register", (req, res) => ({ })) it should be 
router.post("/register", (req, res) =>  {})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses outside the body of the function `(req, res) =>`. It should look like this:

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    // other code inside
});
```

`() => ({})` will expect to return an object literal expression, e.g. JSON object. `() => {}` will execute the statements inside function body.

Read more at MDCN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Syntax

Answer (score 1):

In an arrow function, the syntax you are using here

```
(req, res) => ({})
```

returns an object.

```js
const foo = () => ({foo: 'bar'});
console.log(foo());
```

It's a shorthand for

```js
const foo = () => {
  return {
      foo: 'bar'
  }
};

console.log(foo());
```

So you either need to fix your code to really return a valid object, or remove `({` at the beginning, and the `})` at the end of your function

```
router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
    // ...
});
```